# How to dynamically type properties based on method input (Python)

Tags: python, pydantic

Is there a way to infer the type of a model's attribute based on some kind of parameter?

I'm trying to type the return type of a method that returns a list of objects like for example:

```
{
    "object": "type_depends_on_input_of_method",
    "certainty": 0.8
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that the method accepts a model and returns a specific return type such that the type of "object" is inferred, something like this:

```
CT = TypeVar("CT")

class SearchReturnType(TypedDict, CT):
    object: CT
    certainty: float


class SearchInterface:
    T = TypeVar("T")
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def search(self,
               text: str,
               model: Type[T]) -> List[SearchReturnType(Type[T])]:
```

Is there a way to implement this?

My ideal scenario would be that wheb I do the following, vscode recognizes the type and autocomplete works as it should:

```
search_interface = SearchInterfac()
search_interface_response = search_interface.search("somethin", Document)
first_document = search_interface_response[0].object --> Automatically recognized as a Document
```

Comment: I think you just inherit from `typing.Generic[CT]` rather than `CT`.

Comment: That works! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit from `Generic[CT]` rather than `CT`.

```
class SearchReturnType(TypedDict, Generic[CT]):
    object: CT
    certainty: float
```

Instead of `SearchReturnType` being a kind of `CT`, it's a kind of generic class that *uses* `CT`.